# How can i make this with BigInteger

Tags: arraylist, biginteger

Hi i want to make this code but with BigInteger how i could do it?

Original code

```
int v=100;
ArrayList<Integer>[] lists; 
lists = new ArrayList[v];
```

I want this exact code but instead of int, BigInteger is that possible?, I tried to to this

```
BigInteger v=BigInteger.valueOf(100);
ArrayList<BigInteger>[] lists;
lists = new ArrayList[v];
```

obviously does not work , i want to know which data structure i can use.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)? There you would learn that there are multiple ways to initialize a BigInteger, including for example `BigInteger v=BigInteger.valueOf(100);` Also, the length of java arrays must be less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so only an int can be used to allocate storage for them. BigIntegers cannot be used, not can even longs be used. It has to be an int. Shorter types like byte, short, and char can be used as they are promotable to int without loss of precision.

Comment: that was my bad, i dont know why I put Biginteger v=100 . I know that my code is bad i just want to know how can i change it to be all BigInteger

Comment: What i refer is. which data structure can i use to do the thing i want to do

Comment: The question is: what do you want to do? Create an array of ArrayList? In that case, check out the comment of @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk. You cannot create an array with more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements.

Comment: Want to do a multilist with BigInteger

Comment: You might want to create an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

Comment: That works for me @RobertKock, thanks, now i have another problem, how i can create a matrix of BigInteger n vertex and BigInteger m edges

Comment: You can't possibly store as many values as would require a BigInteger, so you simply call `n.intValueExact()` and `m.intValueExact()` to get the BigIntegers into the correct type.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Thanks, that works